# Drop All Views With A Prefix

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I use this to drop all tables with a prefix, but can it be adapted to drop views?

```
USE [Test]
GO
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
DECLARE cmds CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'drop table [' + Table_Name + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Name LIKE 'XX_%'

OPEN cmds
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  FETCH cmds INTO @cmd
  IF @@fetch_status != 0 BREAK
  EXEC(@cmd)
END
CLOSE cmds;
DEALLOCATE cmds
```

If I use this on a view, I get this error:

> Msg 3705, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'XX_Test' because 'XX_Test' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the error says, you have to `drop view` for views and `drop table` for tables.

try this:

```
USE [Test]
GO
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
DECLARE cmds CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'drop ' 
  + case when table_type = 'base table' then ' table ' else ' view ' end
  +' [' + Table_Name + ']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_Name LIKE 'XX_%'

OPEN cmds
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
  FETCH cmds INTO @cmd
  IF @@fetch_status != 0 BREAK
  EXEC(@cmd)
END
CLOSE cmds;
DEALLOCATE cmds
```